# Image Manipulation library/framework in AS3

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, image-processing, image-manipulation

Is there a good image manipulation library/framework that can be used in a Flash/Flex application? I'm looking for some distortion effects in fotoflexer.com like bulge, pinch, stretch, squish, Smooth Wrinkles?

Any ideas/comments will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [Joa Ebert's image processing library](http://blog.joa-ebert.com/imageprocessing-library/).  Haven't used it myself but Joa is an amazing developer and a quick glance thru the [docs](http://je2050.joa-ebert.com/imageprocessing/) shows a good variety of filters including some of the distortions you're looking for.